# Abstract Methods In Java Method Not Woring Properly

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I am having trouble displaying my compound Interest and Loan on the following problem. I have to have an abstract super class and two methods a set and get to store principle amount, and an abstract set and get to store rate and years. I am clueless on what i am doing wrong when i run the program, the compound and loan stay at 0.0 no matter what i do. Please help!! Thanks! Oh and i also have to create references of the objects which i know how to do. Note: i originally had public double years and public double rate but since it did not work i created year2 rate2 etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Instance of Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Instances
        Guarantee guara = new Guarantee();
        CompoundInterest compI = new CompoundInterest();
        Loan borrow = new Loan();



        System.out.println("Please enter the principle amount: ");
        double principleAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please enter the rate ");
        double rate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the years : ");
        double years = input.nextDouble();

        Funds ref = guara;
        ref.setPrincipleAmount(principleAmount);
        ref.setData(rate, years);
        System.out.printf("With a principle amount of $%.2f , an interest rate of %.2f, and %.2f years, you would have earned $%.2f\n", principleAmount, rate, years, guara.getData());


        ref = compI;
        ref.setData(rate, years);
        System.out.printf("With a principle amount of $%.2f, an interest rate of %.2f, and %.2f, you would have a compound interest of $%.2f\n", principleAmount, rate, years, ref.getData());




        //Instances



    }//End main

}//End class


//Super class
abstract class Funds{
    //Instance variables
    public double principleAmount;
    public double rate;
    public double years;
    public double rate2;
    public double rate3;
    public double year2;
    public double year3;
    public void setPrincipleAmount(double principleAmount){
        this.principleAmount = principleAmount;
    }//End setPrincipleAmount

    public double getPrincipleAmount(){
        return principleAmount;
    }//End getPrincipleAmount

    public abstract void setData(double rate, double years);
    public abstract  double getData();




}//End abstract class Funds


class Guarantee extends Funds{

    @Override
    public void setData(double rate, double years) {
        this.rate = rate;
        this.years = years;

    }

    @Override
    public double getData() {
        return (principleAmount * rate * years);


    }




}//End sub class Guarantee


class CompoundInterest extends Funds{

    @Override
    public void setData(double rate, double years) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.rate = rate2;
        this.years = year2;

    }

    @Override
    public double getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (principleAmount * Math.pow(1 + rate2, year2));
    }




}//End sub class CompundInterest

class Loan extends Funds{

    @Override
    public void setData(double rate, double years) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.rate = rate3;
        this.years = year3;
    }

    @Override
    public double getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (principleAmount * rate3 * year3) + principleAmount;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't figured out assignment.  In `x = y;`, the variable `x` gets the value of the variable `y`.  So all your assignments are around the wrong way. `this.rate = rate3;` should be `this.rate3 = rate;`, and so on.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answering my question however, i would just mirror the image backwards. Y = X and its true since x = y y must be equal to x. I have tried it like that and it still stays at 0.0

Comment: `x = y` isn't a comparison, it's an assignment. Reversing it is not sensible.

Comment: Yes just confirmed the assignment of the variables does not impact anything. Thanks so much for answering though!

Comment: There are many other bugs in this code, but that's the one that's going to cause you the most problems, initially. Try a much simpler problem first; you're biting off too much for your first attempt.

Comment: Ahh ok i know what you meant now and sorry but this.rate = rate3; did not work, originally i had it all to set: this.years = years; and this.rate = rate; all classes were set exactly like that without the rate2 rate3 or year2 year3.

Comment: Hmm i am lost oh great expert!! :( i have no clue how to bring my compound and loan out of the zeros! my arguments are passing so i have no clue! My calculations are right too!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void setData(double rate, double years) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.rate = rate2;
    this.years = year2;

}
```

should be

```
 @Override
public void setData(double rate, double years) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.rate2 = rate;
    this.years2 = year;

}
```

Please recheck your assignments. They seem to be incorrect.

Comment: Ok will do but i orginally had my code to have all classes do this : this.rate = rate; this.years = years. I know that in the above it must be this.rate2 = rate; and this.rate3 = rate; correct? or am i missing something? But still with all these variables assignments i have flipped, put back, destroyed, re created, made more but my compound and loan stay at 0.0